# Wordpress - Where do conditional tags go in header.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, conditional-statements

I want to put this conditional tag, excluding my navigation menu from my 'shop' page, into my header.php

```
<?php if ( !is_page( 'shop' ) ) { 
  wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'show_home' => 'Home', 
    'container' => 'false', 
    'theme_location' => 'main') 
    ); 
  }
  endif;
  ?>
```

Perhaps the code is wrong but when I paste it into the beginning of header.php, the whole site crashes!

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Note the `:` in the first line. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?php
if ( !is_page( 'shop' ) ) :
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'show_home' => 'Home',
        'container' => 'false',
        'theme_location' => 'main')
    );
endif;
?>
```

OR:

```
<?php
if ( !is_page( 'shop' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'show_home' => 'Home',
        'container' => 'false',
        'theme_location' => 'main')
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! But I'm still unsure where this code would go in header.php

Comment: @WillWhitehead the code outputs a menu, so you put it where you want your menu to appear..read more about [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)